# Firestore onSnapshot with "where" and "orderBy" not matching any documents

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am struggling to figure out why the following code produces the "doc.empty" console log. The screenshot shows what I see in Cloud Firestore's data console. My abbreviated code is below. In my example, I have the following variables:

```
dataset = '202203aam'
custnum = '19930'
```

[image]

```
firestoredb.collection('sold').doc(dataset).collection('sold').where('custnum', '==', parseInt(custnum)).orderBy('lot', 'asc').onSnapshot(function(doc){
    if (doc.empty){
        console.log('doc.empty');
    } else {
        doc.forEach(function(doc){
            //code here
        });
    }
});
```

Why would this not match my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
.where('custnum', '==', parseInt(custnum))
```

The screenshot shows that your `custnum` field has a string value, yet you are explicitly passing a numeric value in the condition. Strings and numeric values are never the same in the database, so the condition doesn't match the document you how.

To make the query work, make sure you pass the value as the same type that you've stored in the database.

Comment: That makes sense. I changed parseInt(custnum) to custnum.toString() but unfortunately I get the same result, no matching (empty doc).

Comment: You might have other problems in the code, but this was definitely one of them. --- Keep in mind that we can't see the values of any variables you use and don't initialize in the shared code, so it's much more likely that we can help if you reproduce the problem with just hardcoded values.

Comment: When I substitute hard-coded values, I am getting a response from Firestore. So clearly that is where the problem lies. I will keep working on this. Thanks for your help, plugging in values is a good troubleshooting idea.